# CentOS www and cgi-bin directory?

Tags: centos, debian

well I'm use to debian where the public html directory is in var/www  from root

and the cgi bin directory is in usr/lib/

but with centos where are these located?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls /var/www/
```

cgi-bin  error  html  icons